# C#.Net ClearsScript V8 enable modules

Tags: c#, .net, v8, clearscript

Is there a way to enable "import <module>.js;" statements in an embedded V8 Runtime using [Microsoft ClearScript](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript)?

I couldn't find any examples and makes me think I'd have to parse the script file myself first to enable this.

Comment: Usually, the response of the ClearScript team on Github is awesome. [Why not ask there](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript/issues/new) instead of here?

Comment: [Issue created](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript/issues/114).

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. See [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696472/clearscript-javascript-require-functionality) as the basic approach. That question was about enabling CommonJS Require. For ES6 modules approach you will want something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ClearScript;
using Microsoft.ClearScript.JavaScript;
using Microsoft.ClearScript.V8;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            V8ScriptEngine engine = new V8ScriptEngine();
            engine.DocumentSettings.SearchPath = @"c:\temp\js\";
            engine.DocumentSettings.AccessFlags = DocumentAccessFlags.EnableFileLoading;
            engine.AddHostType(typeof(Console));
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from C#");
            engine.Execute(new DocumentInfo() { Category = ModuleCategory.Standard }, @"
                Console.WriteLine('Hello from Javascript');
                import {print} from 'a.js';
                import {add} from 'b.js';
                print(add(30, 12));
                Console.WriteLine('Javascript signing off...');
            ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Where the JS looks like this:

```
// File c:\temp\js\a.js
export function print(txt) {
    Console.WriteLine('The answer to Life etc is ... ' + txt);
  }

// File c:\temp\js\b.js 
export function add(var1, var2) {
    return var1 + var2;
  }
```

Result is:

[image: Output of sample code]

This example is reading files from the local file system as indicated by the AccessFlags = EnableFileLoading setting, with the SearchPath setting giving the path, or paths if given a comma-separated list of paths.

It is the 'ModuleCategory.Standard' option that enables ES6-stylee module loading.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a roll-your-own require() function similar to node.js. I wrote a blog article [here](https://longviewcoder.com/2021/06/23/a-require-for-clearscript/) and there's a [working CodePen](https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/qBryZOZ) to illustrate the approach which was inspired by an [article by Michele Nasti](https://michelenasti.com/2018/10/02/let-s-write-a-simple-version-of-the-require-function.html) which was itself based on the ideas in [chapter 10](https://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html#h_N33QHgUxbG) of the book [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/) by Marijn Haverbeke.

Here is my coded example:

```
const myCode1 = `
  let utils = function (){
    this.say = function(x){
      log('utils: says = ' + x)
      };
      return this;
  }
  exports.utils = utils;
`;
const myCode2 = `
  let customer = function (){
    this.say = function(x){
      log('Customer: says = ' + x)
      };
      return this;
  }
  exports.customer = customer;
`;
/*

*/  
// I am loading simple source code strings into an array - in the real solution
// you would use some kind of source code fetch / load to string process.
let sourceCode = {c1: myCode1, c2: myCode2};
myRequire.cache = Object.create(null); 

function myRequire(name) {   
    log(`myRequire: You require file ${name}`)
    if (!(name in myRequire.cache)) {
        log(`myRequire: ${name} is not in cache; reading from disk`)
        let code = sourceCode[name]; // load the code - this is bespoke to your env      
        let module = {exports: {}};
        myRequire.cache[name] = module;     
        let wrapper = Function("require, exports, module", code);     
        wrapper(myRequire, module.exports, module);
    }
    log(`myRequire: ${name} is in cache. Returning it...`)
    return myRequire.cache[name].exports;
}

// myRequire() produces an object from the 'exports' object in the loaded code.
//let myExports = new myRequire('c1');
// we can then refer to these as 
// let util = myExports.utils();
// or just use 
// let util = new myRequire('c1').utils();

// So...Require c1 will create an object with exports.
let util = new myRequire('c1').utils();
util.say('I am alive!')
 
log("");

// Require c2 will create an object with exports.
let cust = new myRequire('c2').customer();
cust.say('I am alive too!')

function log(msg){
  $('#log').html($('#log').html() + "<br />" + msg);
}
```

The output is

```
myRequire: You require file c1
myRequire: c1 is not in cache; reading from disk
myRequire: c1 is in cache. Returning it...
utils: says = I am alive!

myRequire: You require file c2
myRequire: c2 is not in cache; reading from disk
myRequire: c2 is in cache. Returning it...
Customer: says = I am alive too!
```